# Show/Hide regions in Omega subtheme

Tags: theming

I am using Drupal 7 and I am creating an [Omega](http://drupal.org/project/omega) subtheme.

In my case I want a page without left and right sidebars. But when I inspect the page.tpl.php from alpha theme it contains only code for printing attributes, content and footer regions

Here is my page.tpl.php

```
print $attributes;
  if (isset($page['header']))

   print render($page['header']);

  endif; 

 if (isset($page['content']))

    print render($page['content']);

 endif;

  if (isset($page['footer']))

     print render($page['footer'])

  endif;
```

In the above snipped I don't find any option to show/hide sidebars as we used to do like in Garland theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create multiple page layouts using [delta](http://drupal.org/project/delta/) modules and use the same for required page.

Comment: I created a template but i don't know how to call that template for specific content type. For ex. I have project content type, i want to call that template whenever node of project type will be called how can i achieve it

Comment: Do i have to apply naming convention whilst creating templates ?

Comment: Yes install the [delta](http://drupal.org/project/delta) module as well as the [context](http://drupal.org/project/context) (and context ui) module to control which pages should use the layout. Note: this add alot of admin overhead to change layouts.  If you change the main omega layout, it will not effect any of the predefine layout with Delta.  You have to manually change every one. Don't forget to install the [Omega Tools](http://drupal.org/project/omega_tools) module as well.

Comment: You can use [context](http://drupal.org/project/context) Module to choose template based on the content type.